# Exim - How do I allow only white listed recipients using a catchall router?

Tags: exim

I'm using exim4 with a catchall router to forward mail to a java process.  The java process users are the valid recipients.  I'm trying to reduce the amount of spam routed to the java process by whitelisting the users in exim.

I have tried this in my config file:

```
acl_check_rcpt:

  deny message = invalid recipient
  domains = thedomain.com
  recipients = !/etc/exim4/recipients_whitelist
```

Along with about a billion other things.  I have verified that if I rewrite the condition as just `deny` or `deny recipients = foobar@thedomain.com` the message is rejected but I cannot get the whitelisting approach to work.  I have also tried inverting the logic to accept the whitelisted users but that does not work either.

Here is my router:

```
outer_catchall:
  driver = accept
  transport = dev_null_transport
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
acl_check_rcpt:

  discard    
  !recipients = /etc/exim4/recipients_whitelist
```

The mail addresses of the allowed recipients are listed one per line in /etc/exim4/recipients_whitelist. This file is the whitelist.

Please note the exclamation mark before recipients.

Answer (score 0):

If some recipients are white-listed and others denied - that's quite not a catch all.
Use router like the one below and let the standard ACL recipient verification do the job.

```
outer_java:
  driver = accept
  domains = thedomain.com
  local_parts = /etc/exim4/java_local_parts
  transport = java_pipe
```